# How to do environment variable substitution with AWS CoPilot

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, environment-variables, aws-copilot, aws-copilot-cli

I need to do environment variable substitution from a value from a SSM secret (secrets section in manifest). But escaping doesn't work as the [doco](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/developing/manifest-env-var/#escaping) mentioned.

```
variables:
  TEST1: "https://\\${DATABASE_SERVER}:5000/ReportServer?"
  TEST2: https://\${DATABASE_SERVER}:5000/ReportServer?
secrets:                      # Pass secrets from AWS Systems Manager (SSM) Parameter Store.
  DATABASE_SERVER: /database/server
```

I am getting the following error:
`✘ interpolate environment variables for fisherassist-api manifest: environment variable "DATABASE_SERVER" is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this feature was released in copilot CLI [v1.33.0](https://github.com/aws/copilot-cli/releases/tag/v1.33.0) and I was using a older version. Got support from a ever so helpful mate from [copilot gitter community](https://app.gitter.im/#/room/#aws_copilot-cli:gitter.im)

Secondly, composing Run time variables from other variables is not possible with Copilot at the moment. A similar [feature request](https://github.com/aws/copilot-cli/issues/4790) is there for this.

There are 2 workarounds to achieve this.

#### Approach 1

1. Importing the SSM parameter in [environment addon](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/developing/addons/environment/) as a template parameter
2. [Output](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/developing/addons/environment/#writing-the-outputs-section) the composed value
3. Import the output in the [workload manifest as environment variable](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/developing/addons/environment/#referencing-from-a-workload-manifest)

#### Approach 2

This is a bit complicated workaround is possibly modifying the [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)

1. Create an entrypoint script (entrypoint.sh): This script will export TEST1 and TEST2 using the current value of DATABASE_SERVER and then run your application.

```
#!/bin/sh
export TEST1="https://${DATABASE_SERVER}:5000/ReportServer?"
export TEST2="https://${DATABASE_SERVER}:5000/ReportServer?"

# Now execute the main process of the container

exec "$@"
```

2. Modify your Dockerfile

```
# Copy the entrypoint script into the container
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
# Set the script as the entry point
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["your_application_start_command"]
```

3. In your workload manifest you need

```
secrets:
  DATABASE_SERVER: /database/server
```

This way the DATABASE_SERVER environment variable can be passed at runtime, and entrypoint.sh will set TEST1 and TEST2 accordingly.